# DNS zone fallback file

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have the following DNS zone(bind):

```
zone "." IN {
    type master;
    file "named.root";
};
```

If this zone directive cannot resolve the address, how can I "fallback" to another file for the same directive. Ie something like this:

```
zone "." IN {
    type master;
    file "named.root";
    // fallback file if named.root doesnt resolve
    file "fallback.root";
};
```

Comment: do you have a different set of root servers in your fallback.root file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? *What problem are you trying to solve?*

Comment: @MichaelKjörling In the first named.root I have external root dns servers handling resolution. In the fallback.root, I have local dns servers resolving all of the requests if internet is not available. This way I can do a DNAT to my portal page if no data bearer is available.

Comment: So what you *really want* to ask is "how can I make my resolving DNS server, currently BIND, resolve all host names to a given address if and only if my Internet connectivity is down?". Correct? (Note that such a question does not presuppose any particular solution, and even leaves open the possibility of using other software to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **you can't.**

When you declare a zone in your BIND configuration, you take responsibility for providing full and accurate data about that zone in the zone file that you name in the `file` directive of the `zone` block. That's the major difference especially between [`hint` type zones and other zone types](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html#type).

You can use some text preprocessor to merge multiple files into a single zone file which you then feed to BIND, but that's something entirely different. You'd also have to take care to make it a legal zone file with legal DNS data (can't have two SOAs for the same RRname, for instance).